# Simplifying $\sin\left(\arctan\frac x a\right)$ without geometry

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, inverse-function

I want to simplify the expression
$$\sin\left(\arctan\frac x a\right)$$

I can do this with geometry. In a triangle $ABC$, let $AB=x$, $BC=a$ and $\angle B=90^\circ$. Then, $\arctan\frac xa=\angle C$ and
$$\sin\left(\arctan\frac x a\right)=\frac{AB}{AC}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}$$

> But how to simplify this without geometry; i.e, using trigonometric formulas and algebra?

I tried using the formula:
$$\sin x=\frac{2\tan\frac x2}{1+\tan^2\frac x2}$$ and got the expression $$\sin\left(\arctan\frac x a\right)=\frac{2\tan\left(\dfrac {\arctan\frac xa}2\right)}{1+\tan^2\left(\dfrac {\arctan\frac xa}2\right)}$$
But this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Set $\theta=\arctan{x\over a}$ and use the identity $$\sin^2\theta={\tan^2\theta\over1+\tan^2\theta}.$$

Comment: If you put $\tan(t)=\tfrac{x}{a}$ then $\sec^2(2)=1+\tfrac{x^2}{a^2}$ so $\cos^2(t)=\tfrac{a^2}{x^2+a^2}$. This yields that $\sin^2(t)=\tfrac{x^2}{x^2+a^2}$ which is equivalant to $\sin(t)=\mathbf{sgn}(x)\tfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}$.

Comment: By the way, is this an identity?

Answer (score 2):

Easier with a trig drawing that is the basis of the Pythagorean triangle/thm.

Let $ t= \dfrac{x}{a}= \dfrac{t}{1}=\tan \theta $

Read off directly from the drawing

$$\sin \theta =\pm \frac{ t}{\sqrt{ 1+t^2}} $$

Due to the radical sign we needed to insert $\pm$in front of the fraction.

[image]

This ambiguity meant that our $\theta $ was either in the first ***or*** in the third quadrants.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

By the Pythagorean identities, each trig function can be expressed in terms of the others. Here you can use the identity

$$\sin \theta =\pm \frac{\tan \theta}{\sqrt{ 1+\tan^2 \theta}}, $$

and the result follows (note the $\pm$).

Answer (score 1):

Draw a right-angled triangle with the non-hypotenuse edges having length x and a. The angle opposite x is arctan of x/a. Now, you want to compute sine of this angle. You should know what to do!

Answer (score 1):

I, too, wanted a more rigorous derivation of such formulas but could not find any particularly satisfying ones on this forum. Usually you see a simple reference to a triangle in the first quadrant. I think the following derivation will meet your criteria. The Golden_Ratio's answer provides some of the details, but I  hope to give you a more thorough explanation. For completeness, I will also provide an explanation of $\cos(\arctan(\frac{x}{a}))$.

---

Before dealing with the argument of $\arctan(\frac{x}{a})$, let us simply deal with an arbitrary argument, which I will denote as $(\cdot)$...i.e. let us consider the alternative representations of the functions $\sin(\cdot)$ and $\cos(\cdot)$.

Depending on how you first introduce these functions, the language may be different (e.g. theorem vs definition), but let us agree that the following statements are true: $\sin^2(\cdot)+\cos^2(\cdot)=1$ and $\tan(\cdot)=\frac{\sin(\cdot)}{\cos(\cdot)}$

Then consider the following:

\begin{align}\sin^2(\cdot)=1-\cos^2(\cdot)\implies\frac{\sin^2(\cdot)}{\cos^2(\cdot)}=\frac{1-\cos^2(\cdot)}{\cos^2(\cdot)}\implies \tan^2(\cdot)=\frac{1}{\cos^2(\cdot)}-1 & \implies \tan^2(\cdot)+1=\frac{1}{\cos^2(\cdot)}\\ &\implies \cos^2(\cdot)=\frac{1}{1+\tan^2(\cdot)}\quad (*_1)\end{align}

\begin{align}  \cos^2(\cdot)=1-\sin^2(\cdot)\implies \frac{\cos^2(\cdot)}{\sin^2(\cdot)}=\frac{1-\sin^2(\cdot)}{\sin^2(\cdot)}\implies \frac{1}{\tan^2(\cdot)}=\frac{1}{\sin^2(\cdot)}-1 &\implies\frac{1}{\tan^2(\cdot)}+1=\frac{1}{\sin^2(\cdot)}\\&\implies\frac{1+\tan^2(\cdot)}{\tan^2(\cdot)}=\frac{1}{\sin^2(\cdot)}\\&\implies\sin^2(\cdot)=\frac{\tan^2(\cdot)}{1+\tan^2(\cdot)} \quad (*_2)\end{align}

Okay...so $(*_1)$ and $(*_2)$ will always be true. Next, we need to recall that the $\sqrt{(\cdot)}$ function is defined to have the following relationship with the $|(\cdot)|$ function: $\sqrt{\phi^2}=|\phi|$.

Therefore:

$\sqrt{\cos^2(\cdot)}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\tan^2(\cdot)}}\implies |\cos(\cdot)|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\cdot)}}\quad (*_3)$ and $\sqrt{\sin^2(\cdot)}=\sqrt{\frac{\tan^2(\cdot)}{1+\tan^2(\cdot)}} \implies |\sin(\cdot)|=\frac{|\tan(\cdot)|}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\cdot)}} \quad (*_4)$.

Before continuing, consider the following illustration, which simply clarifies, for the classical 4-quadrant representation of a circle, where $\sin, \cos,$ and $\tan$ are positive $+$ or negative $-$:

[image: 4-Quadrant Depiction]

Dealing with $(*_3)$ first, we know that if the argument $(\cdot)$ refers to a vector position on the circle's circumference in the first or fourth quadrant, then we have:

$|\cos(\cdot)|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\cdot)}} \implies \cos(\cdot)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\cdot)}} \quad (\dagger_1)$

Conversely, if the argument $(\cdot)$ refers to a vector position in the second or third quadrant, then we have:

$|\cos(\cdot)|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\cdot)}} \implies -\cos(\cdot)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\cdot)}} \implies \cos(\cdot)=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\cdot)}}$

Next, let us deal with $(*_4)$, which is slightly more involved due to the presence of $|\tan(\cdot)|$.

Firstly, if the argument $(\cdot)$ refers to a vector position in the first or second quadrant, then we have:

$|\sin(\cdot)|=\frac{|\tan(\cdot)|}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\cdot)}}\implies \sin(\cdot)=\frac{|\tan(\cdot)|}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\cdot)}}$

Note, though, that we now must differentiate between the first or second quadrant two address $|\tan(\cdot)|$. Specifically, if we are in the first quadrant, then:

$\sin(\cdot)=\frac{|\tan(\cdot)|}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\cdot)}} \implies \sin(\cdot)=\frac{\tan(\cdot)}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\cdot)}} \quad (\dagger_{2,a})$.

However, if we are in the second  quadrant, then:

$\sin(\cdot)=\frac{|\tan(\cdot)|}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\cdot)}} \implies \sin(\cdot)=\frac{-\tan(\cdot)}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\cdot)}}$

Now, if the argument $(\cdot)$ refers to a vector position in the third or fourth quadrant, then we have:

$|\sin(\cdot)|=\frac{|\tan(\cdot)|}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\cdot)}}\implies -\sin(\cdot)=\frac{|\tan(\cdot)|}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\cdot)}}\implies \sin(\cdot)=\frac{-|\tan(\cdot)|}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\cdot)}}$

If we subsequently differentiate between the third and fourth quadrant...the third quadrant yields:

$\sin(\cdot)=\frac{-(+\tan(\cdot))}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\cdot)}}\implies \sin(\cdot)=\frac{-\tan(\cdot)}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\cdot)}}$

...and the fourth quadrant yields:

$\sin(\cdot)=\frac{-(-\tan(\cdot))}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\cdot)}}\implies \sin(\cdot)=\frac{\tan(\cdot)}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\cdot)}} \quad (\dagger_{2,b})$

We have thus compiled all of the different relationships depending on which quadrant the $(\cdot)$ argument places us. **We can now deal with $\arctan(\frac{x}{a})$**, which, of course, must fall into at least one of the above arbitrary arguments. Importantly, though, $\arctan$ is an inverse *function*. Classically, $\arctan$ is defined to be the inverse of the **restricted** $\tan$ function, where the domain of said 'restricted $\tan$' function is $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$. Note, this domain restriction is precisely equivalent to describing the first and fourth quadrants.

As such, if we are interested in evaluating the expression $\cos(\arctan(\frac{x}{a}))$, we can reference $(\dagger_1)$, which tells us that:

$\cos(\arctan(\frac{x}{a}))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\arctan(\frac{x}{a}))}}\implies \cos(\arctan(\frac{x}{a}))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{a^2+x^2}{a^2}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{a^2}}}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}$ .

And, to address you specific question, if we want to evaluate $ \sin(\arctan(\frac{x}{a}))$, noting that $(\dagger_{2,a})$ and $(\dagger_{2,b})$ are, **in fact**, equivalent, we have:

$ \sin(\arctan(\frac{x}{a}))=\frac{\tan(\arctan(\frac{x}{a}))}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\arctan(\frac{x}{a})}}\implies \sin(\arctan(\frac{x}{a}))=\frac{\frac{x}{a}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}=\frac{\frac{x}{a}}{\sqrt{\frac{a^2+x^2}{a^2}}}=\frac{\frac{1}{a}x}{\frac{1}{a}\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}$